# How can I make symmetric bezier?

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

I'm trying to figure out on how can I make symmetric Bezier curves.

Symmetric here means something different than InkScape's interpretation:

Consider this path segment:

[image]

I want to make it *symmetric* to each other like this:

[image]

So I'm looking for the key-combination or technique to grab only one side of a path, and adjust both ends symmetrically, but horizontally mirrored.

How can I achieve this?

(If I don't want to create a half path, and then mirror it, then rotate it.)

Comment: Snap to grid make handles symmetric. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAOyy.gif

Comment: That only works if the line is either horizontal or vertical (based on my understanding) am I missing something here?

Comment: Well no, just as long as your tangents can snap to your grid. Just make the grid suitably small. For your usecase the grid is almost certainly good enough. The grid just has the same function as rounding numbers just choose a rounding thats appropriate and thats that. But in reality you can rotate the grid to fit your objective. So there is never a situation where its not aligned to the bezier.

Comment: Aham, and there is no way to grab only one handle and make the other handle mirror the distance and angle?

Comment: @Daniel There is. You can use a Smooth node for that, but it won't necessarily make the curve geometrically symmetric. You would still need a grid to align it to.

Comment: Smoothing means different I think: what I need is to grab one handle of one point, and make the next point's handle to mirror my movement. It seems smoothing does different job, and can't really help here for me.

Comment: Not that i am aware of. In not sure it would be super useful. It would be more useful if you could lock the angle. But that too dont exist.

Comment: the way i do this when i need it, is draw a line from tangent to endpoint mirror that and then snap the other tangent. Or you can just you know rotate the line to be horisontal and snap then rotate back, although this is a bit problematic in inkscape because it does not have numeric input like a application should have

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "Symmetric Nodes", not Smooth. But still not going to guarantee symmetry without some kind of guide.  When you pull out one handle the other is mirrored. You can hold down Ctrl as you click and drag handles to constrain to increments of 15 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that I'm not sure what your symmetry concept means. But your battered thick curve may present it perfectly for you because you can filter out the bumps and see the essence. It probably is so clear for you that you do not see any reason to formulate it as a math relation.

Unfortunately I do not have the same inner sight. But I guess: You want a circular arc. It surely is symmetric in relative some axis (see NOTE1)

Actually you should decide a third condition to make only one arc valid. If only 2 points are declared, infinitely many arcs will fit.

An example:

[image]

In the left the red circle was drawn first. It was duplicated. The duplicate was colored to green and moved to the other wanted point. The blue circle is also a duplicate of the red one, but moved to the crossing of red and green circles.

The circles snap exactly if you have node, path and center snappings ON.

In the middle the blue circle is split at the corners with the node tool and the unwanted part is moved away.

In the right an arc is drawn directly with the Bezier tool. It draws arcs in Spiro mode. Only click at 3 points (A, B, C) of the arc. The intermediate point B is arbitary as long as there's no 3rd condition declared.

You can move the intermediate point B afterwards with the node tool for visually right appearance. If you want to continue drawing from the ends of the Spiro path by drawing usual Bezier paths you must at first convert the Spiro path to an ordinary path by applying Path > Object to Path.

NOTE1: the symmetry axis is the middle normal of line segment AC in the rightmost image

Comment: This is nice, thx. And yes, I know there are infinite number of symmetric circles that are touching both A and B. I do not know the *spiro* but will check. A B and C are also meaning the click order? I.e. A is first point of Spiro, B is Spiro's *height*, and C is the endpoint?

Comment: The clicking order is ABC. Stop drawing by right clicking. The result is the only possible circular arc which contains points A, B and C. B doesn't present any height. Draw at first the mid normal of the straight line segment AC and click B on it. Then B can be seen as  a height. Draw a line AC and rotate it 90 degrees to make it the mid normal.

Comment: I see. So this will always be symmetric between A and C (as its circular arc)?

Comment: The arc is symmetric when the mid normal of straight line AC is considered as mirror.